# MySQL Group Concat Multiple Select

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a VIEW that concats several select statements, each using conditional rand(), and I’m running into issues with GROUP BY.

I’ve read a number of Stack posts that suggest changing the sql_mode to “only_full_group_by” but that looks like it might just cause more problems.

Each ID has two rows, one for each session (will make more sense when you see the fiddle) which I think is creating the problem.

I removed my GROUP BY attempts from the fiddle so it’s cleaner.

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c8fa6b9f94d7524f7d669a39ace646fa

Comment: It is helpful that you prepared a fiddle to present your data but you forgot to mention what is your expected output. Also what is table3? Finally what is your version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas I would like to concat the three random conditional values. Table3 is from a previous fiddle that didn’t concat the results of the current via were added to Table3 via a trigger. Rather than having the values in separate columns I’m trying to concat them in a view. Version 8.0.25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GROUP CONCAT uis a aggregation function and needs a `GROUP By`

Also you need to concat all values for the GROUP CA

> ```
> -- Table1
>
> CREATE TABLE Table1 (id INT,session VARCHAR(50), value1 VARCHAR(50),
> value2 VARCHAR(50),value3 VARCHAR(50),status VARCHAR(50));
>
> INSERT INTO Table1 (id,session,value1,value2,value3,status) 
> VALUES
> (1,1,1,2,3,'inactive'),
> (1,2,1,2,3,'inactive'),
> (2,1,1,3,4,'inactive'),
> (2,2,2,3,4,'inactive'),
> (3,1,2,3,2,'active'),
> (3,2,2,3,4,'inactive');
>
> select * from Table1
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> id | session | value1 | value2 | value3 | status  
> -: | :------ | :----- | :----- | :----- | :-------
>  1 | 1       | 1      | 2      | 3      | inactive
>  1 | 2       | 1      | 2      | 3      | inactive
>  2 | 1       | 1      | 3      | 4      | inactive
>  2 | 2       | 2      | 3      | 4      | inactive
>  3 | 1       | 2      | 3      | 2      | active  
>  3 | 2       | 2      | 3      | 4      | inactive
> ```

> ```
> -- Table2
>
> CREATE TABLE Table2 (value VARCHAR(50),status VARCHAR(50), 
> results varchar(50));
>
> INSERT INTO Table2 (value,status,results) 
> VALUES
> (1,'active','BRK'),
> (2,'inactive','GOOG'),
> (2,'active','HOG'),
> (3,'active','XOM'),
> (1,'inactive','INTC'),
> (4,'inactive','APPL'),
> (3,'active','NKE'),
> (2,'inactive','SBUX'),
> (1,'inactive','BCE'),
> (1,'inactive','S&P'),
> (2,'active','FB'),
> (5,'inactive','FSLY'),
> (1,'inactive','AMZN'),
> (2,'inactive','ARKK'),
> (3,'inactive','AGEN'),
> (4,'inactive','C'),
> (3,'inactive','TSLA'),
> (2,'active','MSFT');
>
> select * from Table2
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> value | status   | results
> :---- | :------- | :------
> 1     | active   | BRK    
> 2     | inactive | GOOG   
> 2     | active   | HOG    
> 3     | active   | XOM    
> 1     | inactive | INTC   
> 4     | inactive | APPL   
> 3     | active   | NKE    
> 2     | inactive | SBUX   
> 1     | inactive | BCE    
> 1     | inactive | S&P    
> 2     | active   | FB     
> 5     | inactive | FSLY   
> 1     | inactive | AMZN   
> 2     | inactive | ARKK   
> 3     | inactive | AGEN   
> 4     | inactive | C      
> 3     | inactive | TSLA   
> 2     | active   | MSFT
> ```

> ```
> -- Table3
>
> CREATE TABLE Table3 (id INT, session VARCHAR(50), results1 VARCHAR(50),
> results2 VARCHAR(50),results3 VARCHAR(50));
>
> INSERT INTO Table3 (id, session, results1, results2,results3) 
> VALUES
> (1,1,null,null,null),
> (1,2,null,null,null),
> (2,1,null,null,null),
> (2,2,null,null,null),
> (3,1,null,null,null),
> (3,2,null,null,null);
>
> select * from Table3
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> id | session | results1 | results2 | results3
> -: | :------ | :------- | :------- | :-------
>  1 | 1       | null     | null     | null    
>  1 | 2       | null     | null     | null    
>  2 | 1       | null     | null     | null    
>  2 | 2       | null     | null     | null    
>  3 | 1       | null     | null     | null    
>  3 | 2       | null     | null     | null
> ```

> ```
> -- View1
>
> CREATE VIEW view1 AS
>
> SELECT Table1.id,Table1.session, (group_concat(CONCAT('Test:',
>
> (select results from Table2
> where (Table1.status = Table2.status
> and Table1.value1 = Table2.value)
> order by RAND() limit 1),
>
> (select results from Table2
> where (Table1.status = Table2.status
> and Table1.value2 = Table2.value)
> order by RAND() limit 1),
>
> (select results from Table2
> where (Table1.status = Table2.status
> and Table1.value3 = Table2.value)
> order by RAND() limit 1))
>
> SEPARATOR ',')) as concated_column
>
> from Table1
> GROUP BY Table1.id,Table1.session;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT Table1.id,Table1.session, (group_concat(CONCAT('Test:',
>
> (select results from Table2
> where (Table1.status = Table2.status
> and Table1.value1 = Table2.value)
> order by RAND() limit 1),
>
> (select results from Table2
> where (Table1.status = Table2.status
> and Table1.value2 = Table2.value)
> order by RAND() limit 1),
>
> (select results from Table2
> where (Table1.status = Table2.status
> and Table1.value3 = Table2.value)
> order by RAND() limit 1))
>
> SEPARATOR ',')) as concated_column
>
> from Table1
> GROUP BY Table1.id,Table1.session;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | session | concated_column  
> -: | :------ | :----------------
>  1 | 1       | Test:S&PSBUXTSLA 
>  1 | 2       | Test:S&PSBUXAGEN 
>  2 | 1       | Test:S&PAGENAPPL 
>  2 | 2       | Test:SBUXTSLAAPPL
>  3 | 1       | Test:FBXOMMSFT   
>  3 | 2       | Test:GOOGTSLAAPPL
> ```

> ```
> select * from view1;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | session | concated_column  
> -: | :------ | :----------------
>  1 | 1       | Test:BCEGOOGAGEN 
>  1 | 2       | Test:AMZNARKKAGEN
>  2 | 1       | Test:BCETSLAAPPL 
>  2 | 2       | Test:GOOGTSLAC   
>  3 | 1       | Test:FBXOMFB     
>  3 | 2       | Test:ARKKAGENAPPL
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=91c2f36ca3b04a63c8c29d080527e8be)*

Comment: That’s great! Could have sworn I tried that combination of GROUP BY. How come the separator isn’t working?

Comment: figured it out. Didn’t notice your concat inside group_concat at first. Changed concat to concat_ws and added my separator. Works great! Thanks